# JQuery AJAX Call Not Working With error Option

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I'm using AJAX to make calls to my Flask server, but cannot get the error handling to work properly. Currently I have this code that works

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e) {
    const url = "/_do_submit";
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: {
           "value": $("#value").val()
       }
     }).done(function(data){
        alert("good");
    // }).error(function(data){
    //     alert("bad");
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Unfortunately, when I uncomment those two lines to handle errors, the e.preventDefault stops working and the form submits, even for the exact same response. I get the same behavior when I change `.done` to `.success`. I'm not sure if there's something syntactically I need to change, or if I'm not understanding the purpose of these functions. Thank you

Comment: ... read the error message. F12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `error` method on the jqXhr object, what you're looking for is `.fail`

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e) {
    const url = "/_do_submit";
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: {
           "value": $("#value").val()
       }
     }).done(function(data){
        alert("good");
     }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
         alert("bad");
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

---

Actually there was an `error` method but it was deprecated and removed.

Comment: Ooh, you're totally right. Guess I was on some old tutorials or something :p